# Custom Invoice PDF from external source

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

I'm trying to read the invoice pdf from an external source. Can anybody tell me how can I make the external pdf available to the client overriding the one made available by default?

Thanks !

Comment: what want to you actual result ???

Comment: Try Using Mangeto Api - https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-invoice-using-rest-api-magento-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys so, it's actually pretty simple. You have to write a preference for "Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\PrintInvoice".

In your di.xml at (vendor\module\etc\di.xml)

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\PrintInvoice"  type="vendor\module\Controller\MyPrintInvoice"/>
```

Ok now we just have to write the `vendor\module\Controller\MyPrintInvoice.php`

Just create the file in the path above, it should look something like this:

```
class MyPrintInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\PrintInvoice
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $invoiceId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
        if ($invoiceId) {
            $invoice = $this->_objectManager->create(
                \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface::class
            )->get($invoiceId);
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        } else {
            $orderId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
            $order = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::class)->load($orderId);
        }

        if ($this->orderAuthorization->canView($order)) 
        {
                //In here put the code necessary to get your $fileName //
                //In here put the code necessary to get your $file //

                header('Content-type: ' . 'application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: ' . "attachment; filename=$fileName");
                echo $file;
            }              
        } 
        else {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class)->isLoggedIn()) {
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
            } else {
                $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/guest/form');
            }
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
}
```